# how to put continue align to bottom if the text html text is too long in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```
Wrap(
                      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset('assets/img/icon/Member Icon.png', height: 20, width: 20),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Text(
                          "${chatSocketData[index].nickname ?? ''}: ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Html(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          data: chatSocketData[index].message,
                          style: {
                            "body": Style(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: FontSize(12), // Ensure the font size matches the Text widget
                            ),
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
```

Currently, if the html text is too long, it's will move to bottom. What I expected is align together from up to bottom like in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just use the Row and add this child into that. And use expanded over the message so that take the whole remaining space and can easily wrap down.

```html
Row(
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/img/icon/Member Icon.png', height: 20, width: 20),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Text(
          "{chatSocketData[index].nickname ?? ''}: ",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Html(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            data: chatSocketData[index].message,
            style: {
              "body": Style(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: FontSize(
                    12), // Ensure the font size matches the Text widget
              ),
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```